# Find best cell size to use for rasterization from a shapefile

Tags: raster, gdal, ogr, ogrinfo

I've been using GDAL/OGR so far to gather information about my shapefile

```
ogrinfo -so c:/shapefile.shp
```

Using information such as the extents, I can incorporate this into my next command of `gdal_grid` which will transform the shapefile into a raster

My next question is whether an appropriate cell size for rasterizing can be determined from a shapefile using GDAL/OGR?

So for example, when I go to use my `gdal_grid` I can do so as follows

```
gdal_grid  -a nearest:radius1=1:radius2=1:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -txe [determined from ogrinfo] -tye [determined from ogrinfo] -tr [cell size] "C:/shapefile.shp" C:/raster.tif
```

Comment: How small details does your data present? Do you deal with building footprints or oceans?

Comment: @user30184 Bathymetry data, so can be 10 million+ points

Comment: How far apart the points are and how accurate they are? Do they reveal changes in depth at every meter or at every 100 meters?

Comment: @user2856 I know the vector data is bathymetry data and its extents, spatial reference, etc - I had just thought it might be handy if there was a way to calculate an appropriate cell size for raster creation rather than trial and error

Comment: @user2856 my apologies, I will open a new question with more information

Comment: Now asked under https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429946/determine-best-cell-size-for-vector-dataset-based-on-provided-info-from-ogrinfo