# Determine best cell size for vector dataset based on provided info from ogrinfo

Tags: shapefile, ogr, cell-size

I have been using ogrinfo to obtain information regarding my Bathymetry dataset shapefile with the results as follows:

```
Layer name: TEST
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2022-03-30
Geometry: 3D Point
Feature Count: 510518
Extent: (626066.430000, 231758.200000) - (628085.430000, 234095.200000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCRS["OSGB36 / British National Grid",
    BASEGEOGCRS["OSGB36",
        DATUM["Ordnance Survey of Great Britain 1936",
            ELLIPSOID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4277]],
    CONVERSION["British National Grid",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",49,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-2,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996012717,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",400000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",-100000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["United Kingdom (UK) - offshore to boundary of UKCS within 49┬░45'N to 61┬░N and 9┬░W to 2┬░E; onshore Great Britain (England, Wales and Scotland). Isle of Man onshore."],
        BBOX[49.75,-9,61.01,2.01]],
    ID["EPSG",27700]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
X[m]: Real (24.15)
Y[m]: Real (24.15)
Z[m]: Real (24.15)
```

Based on the information above, is there a way to determine the appropriate cellsize for rasterization of this bathymetry data taking into consideration:

- The dataset has 510518 points
- Extent is (626066.430000, 231758.200000) - (628085.430000, 234095.200000)
- In CRS of EPSG:27700 British National Grid

Comment: I think you could have edited your previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429824/find-best-cell-size-to-use-for-rasterization-from-a-shapefile. You still does not describe your data so well. How long apart the bathymetry points are on average? If they are from echo sounder, 1 sounding per second at speed 2 meters per second then one could say that there is no need to create any smaller pixels that 2x2 meters. But if there are 300 meters between the sounding lines then 2x2 meters can be too good resolution.

Comment: @user30184 The data is sent to me, so I have no other information other than what I can obtain from ```ogrinfo```. I was just hoping there was some calculation or something that could be done to determine an appropriate cellsize

Comment: You can open the data, or a sample, with QGIS and have a look. If you have very many points in each resulting raster pixel you will lose some details, but depending on the use case generalization may be desired.

Comment: @user30184 I know I can open the shapefile in QGIS and measure the distance, but is there no calculation method in python for example which could determine the average spacing between points?

Comment: Perhaps calculate the total area by the extent, divide by the number of points and you'll get square meters per point?

Comment: @user30184 just to clarify - ```626066.43 * 628085.43 / 510518``` ?

Comment: I am sure you can resolve that kind of problems and much more difficult ones once you slow down a bit and start thinking. The width of the area in meters is max-min `628085.43-626066.43=2019`.